# Vue - prerender-spa-plugin index.html content undefined

Tags: vue.js, prerender, vue-cli

Hi I installed Vue with the Webpack vue-cli.

I then followed this tutorial for prerendering the html:

https://symmetrycode.com/better-vue-seo-with-prerender-spa-plugin-and-vue-cli/

I'm certain everything should be working fine, it runs the `npm run build` first... but when I open the html file in the `./dist` folder the only thing in there is the word `undefined`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may have just been an outdated version of the `prerender-spa-plugin` or one of it's dependencies. I see new documentation on the `prerender-spa-plugin` page stating that it's an updated version.

Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Run the prerender using `npm run prerender`. Then you can see files generated in `./dist`.

Comment: I am doing that, but when I open the html file in `./dist` this is the contents of the HTML:

`undefined`

Comment: I have added an image to my question that shows what I mean

Comment: `npm run start`; `npm run build` work as expected and eveything works fine. The `npm run prerender` first runs the `npm run build` task before it does it's thing.... but when I look in the html file in `./dist` all I get is `undefined`